# How to place output from the Notepad++ Run command to the current file's cursor position?

Tags: powershell, output, notepad++, clipboard, datestamp

I have a simple one line run script in Notepad++ that sends the output of a Powershell script to the clipboard.  I'm trying to send the output directly to the current cursor position in the current file.  Yes, just to save a keyboard stroke...  I'm using the "Run > Run..." menu option.

Note: The version of Notepad++ I'm using is 7.5.1 (64bit)

```
    powershell.exe $("Set-Clipboard '------------------------------------------------------' ; Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt' | Set-Clipboard -Append")
```

Comment: Of course, if anyone has a better way to add a date stamp to this version of Notepad++, please let me know.

Comment: Maybe a plugin would be a better way to do it. This would allow you to insert text directly, without destroying clipboard content. There is "Automation Scripts" plugin which provides a way to write plugins in C# script, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Good idea, unfortunately we can't install any plugins at my place of work.  Apologies, I should have mentioned that in the question.  Maybe I'll give it a go at home.

Comment: My workplace now allows VSCode to be used.  User snippets are awesome.  As an aside, it's so nice to have a more 'standard' regex flavour.